# 100% Disk Usage Win10 Security Programs

Tags: windows, anti-virus

When running Win10 on my laptop, using any security software, Avast!, Win Defender, causes constant 100% disk usage. As soon as I turn off RTS with Defender, it jumps down to 0.
This isn't my main PC, do I need an antivirus if I only download from reputable sites?
And any ideas how to fix this? I'm doing an SFC scan right now.

Comment: Yes, you need AV, because drive-by downloads and “malvertising”.

Comment: Any recommendations for low disk usage AVs then? Since it seems either I'm having an issue with them, or this laptop can't handle even Defender.

Comment: Windows Defender, by itself, does only on-access scanning. So something else is accessing files.

Comment: As soon as I disabled RTS, disk usage dropped from 100 to 0 instantly. Something that is linked to it? I'll re-enable and look in resource monitor

Comment: soon as SFC is over that is

Comment: Now its just randomly jumping from 100 to 0. MsMpEng.exe is making scan logs using a lot of disk, many logs at a time. Whenever I launch a new program now, it goes flat 100 with MsMpEng scanning everything it uses. I will assume its just my laptop being too slow to handle that

Comment: After launch goes down to 0 again.

Comment: get a faster disk (SSD)

Comment: Disabling Superfetch seemed to fix it. I haven't noticed any slower boot or app load times, however disk usage is normal again.

Answer (score 0):

You should not run two anti-malware applications simultaneously as they will interfere with each other (though you can do a one-time scan of specific files with a second tool, such as Malwarebytes) . Avast! should have disabled the Windows Defender engine. If it did not, **uninstall** Avast! and then reinstall it.

Though Avast! is an excellent tool, you might try Avira or other free AV suite if you still experience the issue.